# Prove that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Let $\phi$ : $\mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z}$ -> $\mathbb{Z}$ be the function defined by $\phi(a, b)$ = $a$ - $b$. Prove that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Definition of a homomorphism: Let $G, H$ be groups. A function $\phi$ : $G$ -> $H$ is a *homomorphism* if for all $a, b \in G$, $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$. (sometimes say in this case that $\phi$ "respects the group structures.")

Hence, I need to show that for any $a, b \in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z}$, $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$.

I do not know what $\mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z}$ is. Likewise, I am unsure on how to show that for any $a, b \in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z}$, $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$ as my function is defined by an ordered pair, namely $\phi(a, b)$ = $a$ - $b$. I would appreciate any feedback!

Comment: $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ is ordered pairs of integers; to make it a group, you need an operation, such as component-wise addition

Comment: your notation is confusing because in some places you have $a,b\in \mathbb Z$ and in others $a,b\in\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I just wrote the definition of a homomorphism so maybe that's why sorry

Comment: using different letters such as $x$ and $y$ instead of $a$ and $b$ for elements of $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ may clarify things for you

Comment: The elements of $\mathbb Z \times Z$ are ordered pairs of integers of the form $(m,n)$, where $m$ and $n$ are in $\mathbb Z$. The standard group operation on $\mathbb Z$, and therefore also on $\mathbb Z \times Z$, is addition, not multiplication. What you need to show is that if $(a,b) \in Z \times Z$ and $(c,d) \in Z \times Z$, then $\phi((a,b) + (c,d)) = \phi((a,b)) + \phi((c,d))$.